# C# Azure Function Limits 250 MB Response Size; I need 2GB response

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-7.0, azure-functions-isolated

All the theory around C# azure function app says no size limitation on response. But practically it limits to 250 MB. Anything more than that produces 0 byte response; no error anywhere. My use case is to return ~2GB response. Here's the production app service plan that I'm using. Do I need to configure anything to increase from 250 MB of the size limitation?

```
foreach(var outputData in outputList)
    await httpResponseData.Body.WriteAsync(outputData);
```

[image][image]

Comment: _"But practically it limits to 250 MB"_ - how did you make that determination?

Comment: Could this in any way be related to IIS settings? For example, the setting maxAllowedContentLength?

Comment: Are you sure there's not a better way to achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Dai I tried with other parameters which can give less than 250 MB of result. If it exceeds 250 MB, it returns empty result. However the same function app in my local machine, gives me the full result always; all ~2GB data.

Comment: @Adam , I haven't setup any such settings. I've checked all the config files, no such settings.

Comment: @Skin, I tried sending to storage account but it makes the program slower. Can you share some alternatives where I can quickly dump the result?

Comment: @Pandiarajan that's ultimately what I would do.  What or who is the calling application?

Comment: @Skin Will be called for PowerBI reports. Another idea I had was to publish the result to the event hub, but that idea was rejected.

Comment: @Pandiarajan, maxAllowedContentLength is an Internet Information Services (IIS) setting that would exist on the Windows server hosting your application. It is not specific to your application, per se, but how it is accessible through webpage, etc. I thought of this as I had a similar issue years ago with TFS2015 when trying to check in/out large files.